# Return index of all matching values sorted list

Tags: python, binary-search

I was recently given this in an interview and have been unable to solve it. Given a sorted list:

```
li = [1,2,2,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5...]
```

Return the index of all elements matching a target, `ex. 4`, with O(log n) time complexity.

The setup of this problem suggested to me that it was a binary search problem.  I answered it with something like the below, but haven't been able to come up with anything nicer:

```py
data = [2,3,5,6,8,9,12,12,12,14,17,19,22,25,27,28,33,37]
target = 12

def binary_search(data, target):
    low = 0 
    high = len(data) - 1

    while low <= high:
        mid = (high + low) // 2
        if data[mid] == target:
            return mid
        elif data[mid] > target:
            high = mid - 1
        else:
            low = mid + 1
    
    return False

def return_other_indices(data, target, match_index):
    output = [match_index]

    i = match_index + 1
    while data[i] == target:
        output.append(i)
        i += 1

    i = match_index - 1
    while data[i] == target:
        output.append(i)
        i -= 1

    return output

match_index = binary_search(data, target)
output = return_other_indices(data, target, match_index)
print(output)
```

Is there a nicer way to do this?

Comment: You could use the `bisect` module?

Comment: Define "nicer" please

Comment: @Jab ideally without the second function altogether or at least without using two while loops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you're looking for, but here is a solution using python standard library.

##### using [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) only:

```
from bisect import bisect_left, bisect
start = bisect_left(data, target)
stop = bisect(data, target, lo=start)
output = range(start, stop)
print(list(output))
```

output: `[6,7,8]`

##### older answer:

It is using [`bisect.bisect_left`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) to find the starting point, and [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) to get all elements.

```
from bisect import bisect_left
from itertools import takewhile, islice
left = bisect_left(data, target)
[left]+[i[0]+left+1 for i in takewhile(lambda x: x[1]==target,
                                       enumerate(islice(data, left+1, len(data))))]
```

*NB. the linear version with `takewhile` might be faster when only a few targets are expected and the data if large, otherwise the double bisect will be faster in general*

Comment: It doesn't seem like this would be `O(log n)` using `takewhile()`.

Comment: Well I guess it depends on the number of targets. I assumed the O(log n) part is to find the first target. If you expect many targets (possibly up to `len(data)`, then you have to perform multiple bisects to find the bounds. Let me add an update

Comment: @mozway Though this answer is great for normal usage, but it is highly unlikely that the interviewer will allow this answer

Comment: @AbhinavSinghal if I was the interviewer I'd probably allow it, and then ask how `bisect` would be implemented. Knowing the libraries is important

Comment: Note that the exercise requirements don't require you to `list`ify the `range` (`range` is an immutable sequence of its values so it's the "index of all the values" without actually making them all until someone actually iterates it), which keeps it 100% `O(log n)` (the construction of the `range` is `O(1)`, `list`ifying it is technically `O(n)`, though the per-item work is *much* cheaper than even `takewhile` checking per-item).

Comment: Sure, but this is mostly detail here. I updated the answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you have to take into account what binary search is, and how it works. Now applied to the problem you have to modify looking for the first and the last.

Based on that, perform a search for the first occurrence, and then the last occurrence applying binary search.

By having both indices I make a simple print of the numbers between the interval

```
def findFirstOccurrence(nums, target):
    (left, right) = (0, len(nums) - 1)
    result = -1
    while left <= right:
        mid = (left + right) // 2
        if target == nums[mid]:
            result = mid
            right = mid - 1
        elif target < nums[mid]:
            right = mid - 1
        else:
            left = mid + 1
    return result
    
def findLastOccurrence(nums, target):
    (left, right) = (0, len(nums) - 1)
    result = -1
    while left <= right:
        mid = (left + right) // 2
        if target == nums[mid]:
            result = mid
            left = mid + 1
        elif target < nums[mid]:
            right = mid - 1
        else:
            left = mid + 1
    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
 
    nums = [2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 8, 9, 9, 9]
    target = 5
    
    indexFirst = findFirstOccurrence(nums, target)
    indexLast = findLastOccurrence(nums, target)
    
    if(indexLast == -1 or indexFirst == -1):
        print("Element not found")
    else:
        print(*range(indexFirst,indexLast+1))
```

**UPDATE**

Here an optimiced form of above:

```
def optimicedOccurrence(nums, target, type_of_occurrence):
    (left, right) = (0, len(nums) - 1)
    result = -1
    while left <= right:
        
        mid = (left + right) // 2
        if target == nums[mid]:
            result = mid
            if(type_of_occurrence):
                right = mid - 1
            else:
                left = mid + 1
        elif target < nums[mid]:
            right = mid - 1
        else:
            left = mid + 1
    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
 
    nums = [2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 8, 9, 9, 9]
    target = 5
    
    indexFirst = optimicedOccurrence(nums, target, 1)
    indexLast = optimicedOccurrence(nums, target, 0)
    
    if(indexLast == -1 or indexFirst == -1):
        print("Element not found")
    else:
        print(*range(indexFirst,indexLast+1))
```

Comment: Great answer! ... but printing would be O(n) though. Printing all the indices doesn't make sense since it is a sorted list anyways. We can just print the leftmost and the rightmost index if element exists.

Comment: @AbhinavSinghal, yep you correct, but the question says: Return the index of all elements matching a target. Thats the best solution i think.

Answer (score 0):

Use the bisect module:

```
from bisect import bisect_left,bisect_right

li = [1,2,2,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5]

target = 4
print(*range(bisect_left(li,target),bisect_right(li,target)))

4 5 6 7
```